# javascript - How do I calculate an JavaScript expression called inside a string?

Tags: calculator

I am creating a simple calculator in HTML and I've created an input field. You can type there an sum and it must be calculated. Only, I don't know how...
Example:
I have a string:

```
234-231*Math.sqrt(9)
```

Is there a way to calculate this sum inside the string using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Use the eval() function.
Like so:
eval("234-231*sqrt(9)");

Comment: Thanks It works, but `sqrt` should be replaced by `Math.sqrt`